# <cffileupload> and Database Insert of File Name

Tags: coldfusion

I am having a problem with the cffileupload tag and then inserting the names of the files uploaded into the database.  It seems like there are no hooks back from the CF Action page that would say if it was successful, if the file was renamed, what the new filename is, and

Basically, I want a user to be able to upload mulitple files (up to 10) without a timeout and storing the name of the files in the database.

Any suggestions would be welcome!  I've dug around on the interweb, and there doesn't seem to be any elegant solutions.

Comment: Just a note:  Having no timeout is very difficult.  Most browsers and webservers have their own timeouts on top of what CF uses.  You can set long timeouts for the webserver and CF, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the file is processed by <cffile action="upload">, there's a huge amount of information available via the variable specified in "result". This includes the original filename, the file size, and an indicator of success. [Adobe's docs on cffile](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-738f.html) has the details. Your best bet is to create a temporary file, push the upload to there via cffile, evaluate success or failure, then push it into the database. Something like:

```
<cfset TemporaryFile = GetTempFile(GetTempDirectory(), "myAppTemp") />
<cffile action="upload" destination="#TemporaryFile#"
        fileField="filefield" result="FileResults" />
```

Then you can access your file via the *TemporaryFile* variable, and the filename via *FileResults.clientFile*. *FileResults.fileWasSaved* should indicate success or failure of the upload and subsequent save to disk.